# Bind a single Object's Fields and Values to a two column datagrid vertically Winform

Tags: c#, winforms, reflection, datagridview

I have a model class as below.

```
public class EmployeeModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public double Salary { get; set; }
}
```

I want its fields and values to be mapped to a WinForm DataGridView as shown below.

[image]

I adopted reflection strategy to do this like below.

```
EmployeeModel emp = new EmployeeModel();
emp.Name = "Dev";
emp.Age = 25;
emp.Salary = 150000;

PropertyInfo[] props = typeof(EmployeeModel).GetProperties();
foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
{                
    object val = prop.GetValue(emp, null);
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(prop.Name, val);          
}
```

Now I may need to loop the columns and do some reflection to convert these values to an EmployeeModel object. It feels to me that I am on the wrong track.

I have two questions.

1. What would be the best way to bind a class object to a DataGridView in this way?
2. Suppose my class contains a field(Example, Grade(integer)). This field value needs to be populated as a combobox inside the datagrid with values such as "Manager,Developer,CEO" etc. What would be be needed to do in that case?

Comment: you cannot use different controls(`combobox` and `TextBox`) in same column, maybe you want to use `PropertyGrid` control

Comment: @Fabio - but i can set the second column to combobox and make it appear flat styled for other properties to simulate the same

Comment: Why if exists another control for exactly purpose you need:  [PropertyGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid(v=vs.110).aspx)  or another [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302326.aspx)

Comment: @Fabio - thanks man! that was a revolution for me..Could you add this as an answer? I would accept it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `PropertyGrid` for this purpose:

```
EmployeeModel emp = new EmployeeModel();
emp.Name = "Dev";
emp.Age = 25;
emp.Salary = 150000;
```

If you will add `PropertyGrid` to your form through designer,
then just set a your object to `SelectedObject` and control will handle the rest

```
this.MyPropertygrid.Text = "Employee";
this.MyPropertyGrid.SelectedObject = emp;
```